# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'claimcode' was never awaited. Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback (telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

The portion of the code where i am getting this error.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['redeemcode'])
def get_code(message):
    code = bot.send_message(chatid, "Send the Code to Redeem")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(code, claimcode)


async def claimcode(message):
    code = str(message.text)
    print(code)
    await client.redeem_code(code)
```

The error that i am getting.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1645]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\Genshin Bot>C:/Python310/python.exe "d:/Genshin Bot/genshinbot.py"
C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py:89: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'claimcode' was never awaited
  task(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Can someone please help and tell whats wrong with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a coroutine inside a normal function. Use `asyncio.run`. To learn more about coroutines and tasks, you can refer to this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html.

The code snippet from above can be changed to:

```
import asyncio

@bot.message_handler(commands=['redeemcode'])
def get_code(message):
    code = bot.send_message(chatid, "Send the Code to Redeem")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(code, asyncio.run(claimcode()))

...
```

Comment: `@bot.message_handler(commands=['redeemcode'])
def get_code(message):
    code = bot.send_message(chatid, "Send the Code to Redeem")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(code, asyncio.run(claimcode(message)))` Thank you very much it worked. Also passed the message parameter through that function